# Working with MaterialCalendarView

Tags: java, android, calendarview

I try a lot, to manipulate that thing. I want to add a `popup-window` every time i click in some number of the calendar.

```
public class TabAgendaFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Agenda";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_agenda_fragment, container, false);

        MaterialCalendarView materialCalendarView = (MaterialCalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        materialCalendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

How i do this, i try to create a `popup` windows inside on the `OnDateSelectedListener`, but with no success. Someone can help me? thanks :)

Comment: _with no success_ means you get any error? can you show us how did you create the pop-up window

Answer (score 2):

You can create poup-window on onDateSelected method with out any issue,May be in your case activity is not created hence you should write your code once activity created.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    MaterialCalendarView materialCalendarView = (MaterialCalendarView) getView().findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    materialCalendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("My Message").setTitle("Title");
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```